# Power BI Rest Source Unable to schedule refresh of dynamic data source

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerquery

I have been building a working set of code for Power BI and a CRM called Autotask.

It works locally but when uploaded to the cloud fails with Unable to schedule refresh of dynamic data source.

I was not expecting it to refresh on a schedule but I did expect to be able to manually update when needed but hit this issue.

I feel confident that this is due to the dynamic URL but not sure how I can resolve as the API requires it to be called in this way for paging.

I'm hoping some one out there with more experince with this than my self may be able to propose a way forward.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT I've also leaned in on this video too but not sure what I am missing - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstsQMZiHME

Terran

```
    let

// {"filter":[{"id":"gte","value":"0"}]}

// searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""id"":""gte"",""value"":""0""}]}",
// {"filter":[{"op":"gte","field":"id","value":"0"}]}
searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",

searchParam = Uri.EscapeDataString(searchFilter),
headers = [Headers = [
                #"ApiIntegrationCode"="xxxxxxx",
                #"UserName"="xxxxxxx",
                #"Secret"="xxxxxxx",
                #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],
baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Contracts/query?search=" & searchParam,

initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(baseuri, headers)),
    initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri 
            newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
            //get new req & data
            newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)),
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    outputList = if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, baseuri),
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(expand,{{"id", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Modded code: **Check Security on data source in Power BI

```
let
// NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication

    // Common parameters
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    headers = [#"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar, #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar, #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar, #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar],
    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",        


//initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)),
initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
//initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error apiUrl,

initData = initReq[items],
    //We want to get data = {lastNPagesData, thisPageData}, where each list has the limit # of Records, 
    //then we can List.Combine() the two lists on each iteration to aggregate all the records. We can then
    //create a table from those records
    gather = (data as list, uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri
            // newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headersgatherfunc))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
            newUri = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]]))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 2nd Pass",
            //get new req & data
            newReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 3rd Pass",
            newdata = newReq[items],
            //add that data to rolling aggregate
            data = List.Combine({data, newdata}),
            //if theres no next page of data, return. if there is, call @gather again to get more data
            check = if newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then data else @gather(data, newUri)
        in check,
    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    //outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI)otherwise error uri,
    outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, apiUrl)otherwise error "Failed outputList",
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Progress made but need to work out why gatherpagingdata fucntion is failing causing the rest of it to.

```
let
// NB Making calls to multiple instances from the same Power BI Dash can cause problems with authentication
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstsQMZiHME
// check data source security

    // Common parameters
    //texttoconv = "dddd",
    //text = texttoconv as text,
    queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringUserNamevar = "xxxxxxxx",
    queryStringUserSecretvar = "xxxxx",
    queryStringContentTypevar = "application/json",
    headers = [#"ApiIntegrationCode"=queryStringApiIntegrationCodevar, #"UserName"=queryStringUserNamevar, #"Secret"=queryStringUserSecretvar, #"Content-Type"=queryStringContentTypevar],
    apiUrl = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query",
    apiUrlnew = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Projects/query/next",
    searchFilter = "{""filter"":[{""op"":""gte"",""field"":""id"",""value"":""0""}]}",           





//Functions

newURIwhatisit = (uri) =>
        let
            //build new uri search string

            newURIwhatisitfuncget = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]]))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "New Func URL Get",      

            //Lets get the search string
            // Text.BetweenDelimiters("111 (222) 333 (444)", "(", ")"),
            //nextPageUrlStaticfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, " ", "?"),
            //queryStringnewfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "?", " "),
            //pagingnewvarfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "?", "pageSize"),
            //pageSizenewvarfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "pageSize", "previousIds"),
            //previousIdsnewvarfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "previousIds", "nextIds"),
            //nextIdsnewvarfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "nextIds", "search"),
            //searchnewvarfunc = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newUridata, "nextIds", "filter")
            
            //queryStringnew = Text.BetweenDelimiters(outputListgather, "?", " "),
            //nextPageUrlStaticsearchpaging = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newURIwhatisitfuncget, "paging=", " "),
            nextPageUrlStaticsearchsearch = Text.BetweenDelimiters(newURIwhatisitfuncget, "paging=", " "),
            newURIwhatisitfunc = nextPageUrlStaticsearchsearch

        in newURIwhatisitfunc,

newURIdatagather = (uri, nextpagefunc) =>
       let
            //build new uri
            newURIdatafuncget = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, [Headers=headers, Query=[paging=nextpagefunc]]))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] otherwise error "New Func URL",
            newURIdatafunc = newURIdatafuncget[items]
        in newURIdatafunc,       

gatherpagingdata = (data as list, uri) =>
    let
        // Get the Data
        newReq = try newURIdatagather(uri, nextpage) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API",
        newdata = newReq[items],
            
        // Add that data to rolling aggregate
        updatedData = List.Combine({data, newdata}),

        // Check for the next URL using function
        nextPageUrl = newReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
        //nextpagefunc = newURIwhatisit(nextPageUrl),
        nextpagefunc = newURIwhatisit(nextPageUrl),

        // If there's no next page of data, return. If there is, call @gather again to get more data
        result = if nextPageUrl = null then updatedData else gatherpagingdata(updatedData, apiUrlnew, nextpagefunc)
    in
        result,





//Execute
    //initReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)),
    initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers=headers, Query=[search=searchFilter]])) otherwise error "Failed to retrieve data from the API 1st Pass",
    //initReq = try Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl, headers)) otherwise error apiUrl,
    initData = initReq[items],


    //before we call gather(), we want see if its even necesarry. First request returns only one page? Return.
    //outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gather(initData, BaseURI)otherwise error uri,
    nextPageUrl = initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl],
    outputList = try if initReq[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] = null then initData else gatherpagingdata(initData, nextPageUrl)otherwise error "Failed outputList",
    //then place records into a table. This will expand all columns available in the record.
    expand = Table.FromRecords(outputList)
in
    expand
```

Answer (score 1):

The BaseURI needs to be static.  You can add the search parameters to the "Query" argument of Web.Contents.

```
         Json.Document(
           Web.Contents(
             "https://data.gov.uk/api/3/action/package_search",
             [Query=[q=Term]]
            )
           ),
```

As Chris Webb explains here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/23/web-contents-m-functions-and-dataset-refresh-errors-in-power-bi/

Comment: Thanks David for your input... my logic was that as far as Power BI was concerned baseuri = "https://webservices4.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Contracts/query?search=" & searchParam gave me the static URL as it does not change or is it newUri = Json.Document(Web.Contents(uri, headers))[pageDetails][nextPageUrl] I should be looking at ? Thanks T

Comment: Both need to be static.  So you may need to break apart nextPageUrl into a static BaseUri and dynamic Query.

Comment: Brilliant... I shall have a look.

Comment: Hi David - I believe I have updated the code in line with your suggestion but I'm getting a "(405): Method Not Allowed" error. Are you able to critique my code please as I'm still getting my head around the diffrences here. Thanks T

Comment: That means you used the wrong HTTP method. GET, POST, PUT, etc

Comment: Thanks that's what's confusing me as the code was good bar the dynamic changes. Do I need to specify a GET within the parameters assuming it's defaulting to http ? Based on this "The HTTP request is made as either a GET (when no Content is specified) or a POST (when there is Content). POST requests may only be made anonymously" I expected it to go through. T

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents

Comment: Found the issue... a couple of vars where getting messed up which where working fine before I used web.contents. I've started progressing (following an instance upgrade too) the code and hopefully will post the finished item here in the future. T

Comment: This took some time as our CRM was migrated and my details needed to be fixed however I have just added what I thought was dynamic code based on your link and I still have the same issue. I pass querys and headers through and use the static url. Can you see where I am failing in my code please as this I think is just a little beyond my skills at this time ? Thanks T

Comment: There's a Web.Contents that uses a URL retrieved from a previous Web.Contents call `newReq = Json.Document(Web.Contents(newUri, headers)),`

Comment: Hi - @david - this was because I get the URL I need to call (which is diffrent each time) from the previous call - [pageDetails][nextPageUrl]. I'm wondering if I need to break down that in to a function of its own then ?

Comment: I believe you need to discover the base url for the subsequent pages and hard-code that in your query, then add whatever the dynamic part is back to it.

Comment: Thanks - done so many iterations of this now starting to struggle a bit (started in March lol). Progress made but need to work out why gatherpagingdata fucntion is failing causing the rest of it to when I get some time.